# Does Windows 7 with platform update support desktop duplication?

Tags: windows-7, directx-11, screen-capture

The articles in MSDN are misleading and doesn't provide a clear answer whether or not Windows 7 with platform update will support desktop duplication. 
Did anyone know if this is possible? I am developing an application for desktop streaming, I currently use mirror driver for windows 7, but i am looking for a common solution for windows 7 and windows 8.

I have win8 SDK and VS2010 for development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Platform Update for Windows 7 on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/jj863687.aspx) answers this question explicitly (highlights added)

> Some new methods introduced in DGXI 1.2 are not fully supported with the Platform Update for Windows 7.You can test for the availability of these functions by calling them directly and checking for an error code. Make sure your applications targeting Windows 7 with the platform update have a fallback in place when the desired functionality is unavailable. These classes of features are **unavailable** on Platform Update for Windows 7:
>
> ...
>
> - **Desktop duplication**
>
> ...

See also [DirectX 11.1 and Windows 7](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/11/14/directx-11-1-and-windows-7.aspx), [DirectX 11.1 and Windows 7 Update](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2013/02/26/directx-11-1-and-windows-7-update.aspx), [KB 2670838](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2670838)